# What is the best way to point a toplevel domain to an url?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, cross-browser, cross-domain, frames

i have the following situation, due to the IT departement at our university, i had three choices to point a top level domain to the content hosted at the university server:

- Redirect
- use frames
- use a reverse proxy

i know frames are deprecated and suck, however getting a server where i can set up a reverse proxy sounded like a bit of an overkill and redirect was not an option, as the dirty url of the webapp server would appear in the addressbar.

So, when i looked up the site in Chrome, i got the message that the site contains unsafe content, opening the console told me that the "unsafe content" are the Google Webfonts i included in the page. All other browsers worked just fine...

Does anyone have an elegant solution for this? I'm not really happy with using frames in the first place.

Thank you guys in advance, cheers!

I will of course provide all the config files/code snippets needed!!

Comment: Is just hosting it elsewhere an option?  Since you don't want the university's URL showing up anyway.

Comment: Thing is, i'm going to need a dedicated server for that and the university doesn't want it to be hosted elsewhere, as it is an university project...

Comment: Is it completely out of the question to persuade the IT dept to actually add a virtual host for your domain name and then simply add an `A`/`AAAA` record(s) for the domain pointing to the server IP? That would be the actual best way. Also, you should post the actual frameset HTML that you're using for your current solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and cleanest option in this case would be reverse proxy with URL rewriting (if you don't like the webapp's ones). If you post your endpoints we'd be able to prepare ones for you. Or check whatever tutorial (for e.g. [this](http://www.askapache.com/hosting/reverse-proxy-apache.html), [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/reqpro/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.reqpro.install_upgrade.doc/topics/rw_apache.html) or [this](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/10825_3290851_3/Reverse-Proxying-With-Apache-20.htm))

One important thing which nobody mentions is to use the `ProxyPreserveHost` directive if on other end you deal with headers processing.

Also you may consider Forward Proxy instead of Reverse one, its easier to configure.

Complete reference [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Answer (score 1):

Mixing http and https, may be the cause of the unsafe content error.  Be sure you are loading the pages and the fonts with the same protocol.

As for pointing your domain, I like the virtual host solution above.  If your IT department says that everything else is "impossible", you might be stuck with frames.  :)